# Problems with filtering react-table-v6 with react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-table-v6

So I must use react table v6. Under the table I use react-select. But when I am trying filtering data in the table something going wrong. It just does not work. l will show you example of request witch I am using. And how I am trying filter data in a table.

Here is my react-select where I providing options and chanhleChange fn:

```
<Select
    onChange={handleChange}
    isMulti
    options={options}
/>
```

Here is handleChange fn:

```
const handleChange = v => {
  setSelectedOptions(v);
  console.log('handleChange value :', v);
};
```

For providing options in select with react-select library you need that trick (why so hard i dunno...).

```
const options = tags.map((i) => ({
  value: i,
  label: i,
}));
```

Here I flatten local state selectedOption, coz I want to use it as value in "includes" method

```
const flatenSelectedOption = selectedOption?.map(item => item?.value).flat();
```

After selection in the select, the data looks like, that why I flat them using **flatenSelectedOption** :

```
choosenOptionsFromselect: [
  0: {value: 'Country', label: 'Country'}
  1: {value: 'Carrier', label: 'Carrier'}
]

flatenSelectedOption : (2) ['Country', 'Carrier']
```

Then here I trying filter table depent on values in select.

```
const sortedTableByTags = tableData.filter((item) =>item.tags?.name?.includes(flatenSelectedOption));
```

Then here is simple rule. I we chosen some value from select we should use filtered array, if not show all data.

```
<ReactTable
     data={(selectedOption?.length === 0 || selectedOption == null) ? tableData : sortedTableByTags}
```

But sorting does not happen, when I select something from the select, I get an empty table
Below if you follow the link you can see a small gif and a screenshot of the console
[console.log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO0f2.png)

[Gif - Select work](https://gyazo.com/1ee2f69d86045a47af2502a387788592)

Comment: can you share your code at https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: This is only one part of big application, probably I will try copy part and paste there

Comment: sure, you can do that

Comment: just cant add react-table v6.11.5 to codecandbox Error
Could not fetch dependencies, please try again in a couple seconds:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys I solve my own problem with sorting. It helped me sort data in a table.

```js
const sortedTableByTags = useMemo(() => tableData.filter((item) => item?.tags?.filter(i => i?.name?.includes(selectedOption))), [tableData, selectedOption]);
```

Second improvement which I did i was changing onChange select function to.

```js
const handleSelectChange = v => {
    const res = v?.map(item => item.label);
    setSelectedOptions(res);
};
```